# State video cannot use the map function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, youtube-api

I am currently trying to build a movie app using React. In this case, I tried to display a video from YouTube with the TMDB API. But an error occurred when trying to access the key. How can I fix it?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'
import { fetchMovie } from '../../../manage/action'
import style from './style.module.css'
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import {faStar} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import Youtube from 'react-youtube'
import { movieList } from '../../../service/api/api'

function ContentComing() {

    const {id} = useParams()
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    // state
    const [video, setVideo] =useState([])
    const {coming} = useSelector((state) => state.upComing)

    const fetchMovieUpComing = async(comingId) => {
        await dispatch(fetchMovie(comingId))
    }

   // Data API key for YouTube
    const fetchVideo = async(movieId) => {
        try {
            const respone = await movieList.get(`/movie/${movieId}/videos?api_key=${import.meta.env.VITE_TMDB_KEY}&append_to_response=videos`)
            return respone.data.results[1]
        } catch (error) {
            return error
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchMovieUpComing(id)

        // Render API function to state
        setVideo(fetchVideo(id))
        console.log(fetchVideo(id))
    },[])

    return (
        <>
            <div className={style['wrapper']}>
                <div className={style['detail-movie']}>
                    <div className={style['image-movie']}>
                        <img src={`${import.meta.env.VITE_IMG_PATH}${coming.poster_path}`} alt='poster' />
                    </div>
                    <div className={style['content-movie']}>
                        <p className={style.title}>Title: {coming.title}</p>
                        <div className={style['rating']}>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar} className={style['icon']} size='2x'/>
                            {coming.vote_average}
                        </div>
                        <p>Release Date: {coming.release_date}</p>
                        <hr />
                        <div className={style['genre']}>
                            <p>Genre:</p>
                            {coming.genres.map((item) => {
                                return (
                                    <p key={item.id}>{item.name}</p>
                                )
                            })}
                        </div>
                        <p>Language: {coming.original_language}</p>
                        <p>Overview: {coming.overview}</p>
                        <p>Popularity: {coming.popularity}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={style['video-movie']}>

                    {/* state video */}
                    {video.map((item) => {
                        return (
                            <Youtube videoId={item.key}/>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default ContentComing
```

The data result of the *fetchVideo* function is an array, so the useState uses [].

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlw28.png)

Comment: Try removing the variables in the url and add hard coded values just to check what's wrong there, may be the issue is with api.

And also share the error snapshot here

Comment: Mixing `fetch` logic up between redux and local state doesn't seem manageable. Ideally you'd pick one or the other.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76440232/edit). Thanks in advance.